# Laravel 5 pagination Call to a member function render() on a non-object

Tags: pagination, laravel-5

I am trying to paginate some categories and this error popped up from nowhere and I don't know how to fix it :

> Call to a member function render() on a non-object

This is my controller:

```
public function getFilmeByCateg()
{
    $categorii = Categorii::all();
    //$Movies = Movies::all();
    $categorie = Request::segment(2);
    $cat = Categorii::where('denumire', '=',$categorie)->first();
    $cat2 = Categorii_filme::where('categorie_id', '=' ,$cat->categorie_id)->get();

$filme = array();

foreach($cat2 as $filmulet)
{

$film = Movies::where('movie_id','=',$filmulet->film_id)->paginate(12)->first();
$filme[] = $film;


}

 return view('filme')->with('Movies',$filme)->with('categorii',$categorii);
}
```

And this is how I render the paginator in my layout:

```
{!!$Movies->render() !!}
```

This is in my routes:

```
Route::get('categorie/{categorie}','WelcomeController@getFilmeByCateg');
```

This is in my Movies.php:

```
class Movies extends Model {

protected $table = "movies";
}
```

Can someone tell me how can I manage to make this work ?

Comment: Your code is a real mess.
Can you show us your route declaration to this method ? And why do you have Category_filme Class ? Is this class representing your pivot table between your movies and your categories ?

Comment: yes in categorii_filme i have the category id and the movie id

Comment: I'm guessing you're new to Laravel. I can't do more than advise you to read carefully the laravel Eloquent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$filme` is an array, you can access `render()` method whose object you wanted is `$Movies` which is array.

```
foreach($cat2 as $filmulet)
{

    $film = Movies::where('movie_id','=',$filmulet->film_id)->paginate(12)->first();
    $filme[] = $film;
}
```

Here `$filme` is an array.

```
return view('filme')->with('Movies',$filme)->with('categorii',$categorii);
```

Here you passed `$filme` as `$Movie` variable.

```
{!!$Movies->render() !!}
```

And here you wanted to access `render()` method of `$filme` which is not an object.

Change your controller to this:

```
public function getFilmeByCateg()
{
    $categorii = Categorii::all();
    //$Movies = Movies::all();
    $categorie = Request::segment(2);
    $cat = Categorii::where('denumire', '=',$categorie)->first();
    $movie_ids = Categorii_filme::where('categorie_id', '=' ,$cat->categorie_id)->get()->lists('movie_id');


    $filme = Movies::whereIn('movie_id','=',$movie_ids)->paginate(12);


    return view('filme')->with('Movies',$filme)->with('categorii',$categorii);
}
```

Comment: Where do this render() method came from? Do you have render() on Movies model?

Comment: Can you post the movies model too?

Comment: it doesn't work,that render was for pagination,i want the pagination to be shown,i already have the movies showed.

Comment: i changed in the controller but now another error pops up :'Array to string conversion'

Answer (score 0):

OK First of all, you made it the wrong way.
Using an intermediate class for representing the pivot table is completely bad.

I'll make it work for you.

**Your Category class**

```
class Category extends \Model {
   protected $table = 'categories';

   public function movies()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Your\Namespace\To\Movie');
   }
}
```

**Your Movie class**

```
class Movie extends \Model {
   protected $table = 'movies';

   public function categories()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Your\Namespace\To\Category');
   }
}
```

Your route is still :

> Route::get('categorie/{category_id}','WelcomeController@getFilmeByCateg');

So in your controller method you do the following :

```
public function getFilmeByCateg($category_id)
{
   $category = Category::findOrFail($category_id);

   return view('filme')->with('Movies',$category->movies()->paginate(12)->ge())->with('categorii',Category::all());   
}
```

Now in your view `$Movies->render()` will work

Answer (score 0):

If you wont paginate your data how would you render it ? Documents on the official laravel website states :

> There are several ways to paginate items. The simplest is by using the paginate method on the query builder or an Eloquent model.

**Paging database results**

```
$users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);
```

> Note: Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually.

**Creating A Paginator Manually**

> Sometimes you may wish to create a pagination instance manually,
>   passing it an array of items. You may do so by creating either an
>   Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator or
>   Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator instance, depending on your
>   needs.

Now in your case you should first

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator;
```

and then

```
$paginator = new Paginator($items, $count, $limit, $page, [
        'path'  => $this->request->url(),
        'query' => $this->request->query(),
    ]);
```

Please supply parameters accordingly in the Paginator function above.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late but it will help someone who get in to same issue. Instead of `->get()` use `->paginate(10)` in query.